# Traveling from India to port of Spain with transit in Canada, can I enter Canada?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, canada, transit-visas

I'm travelling via Canada, and I have a transit visa. Can I enter Canada?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a Canadian transit visa, you can enter Canada for 48 hours between 2 international flights.

> by air for up to 48 hours between two international flights

Source: [CIC](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas-result.asp?q2=no&country=IN&result=1)